# Merging two dictionaries based on shared keys

Tags: python, dictionary

I have two nested dictionaries that describe citations behaviors of a set of papers. For example, in the following toy examples, `"001"` is cited by `"005"`, which is in turn cited by `"010"` and `"012"`.

```
dict1 = {"001": {"005", "006"}, "002": {"003", "007"}}
dict2 = {"005": {"010", "012"}, "006": None, "003": {"014", "018", "020"}, "007": None}
```

Now I would like to merge two dictionaries into one nested list, which looks like

```
nestedDict = {"001": {"005": {"010", "012"}, "006": None}...}
```

I know this could be easily done by doing something like

```
nestedDict = {key: {val: dict() for val in valSet} for key, valSet in dict1.items()}
for key, valSet in dict1.items():
    for val in valSet:
        nestedDict[key][val] = dict2[val]
```

I am wondering if there is more "direct" way that could replace these four lines of code with something more concise (preferably one-liner)?

Comment: Here is a one-liner: `{k1: {k2: dict2[k2] for k2 in v} for k1, v in dict1.items()}`. But I think that your solution is actually more readable.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use the following:

```
nested_dict = {k1: {v2: dict2[v2] for v2 in v1} for k1, v1 in dict1.items()}
```

This would result in:

```
{'001': {'006': None, '005': set(['010', '012'])},
 '002': {'003': set(['018', '014', '020']), '007': None}}
```